# How to exclude last post from blog page in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I used to write several blog posts in wordpress. I have totally updated 10 posts and its showing 10 posts perfectly.

My question is,

I need only 9 posts to display. The last updated posts should not display on the website. I need the code to exclude the newest post that is 10th post. And i need the code to be placed on functions.php.

Could anyone please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to your `settings` from the `admin pannel` and then click on `reading` then change `blog post at most` to `9`.

Or programatically you can try like

```
 $latestPosts = new WP_Query( array(
                        'posts_per_page'            => 9, 
                        'orderby'                   => 'date',
                        'order'                     => 'DESC',
                      )); // end query

  while ($latestPosts->have_posts()) : $latestPosts->the_post();
```

Comment: Hi gautam, thank u for your reply. This answer displays only 9 posts. But i need to exclude(remove) the last post.

Comment: I am having two columns left and right. In the left section i have written the code to display one post that is the last post(10th post). In the right section, the wordpress code will automatically displays the 10 posts (i didnot write the code). It shows all the 10 posts. I no need the last post(10th post) because it is already in the left section.

Comment: So use the second ans of mine'

Comment: i need to use it in functions.php